# Azure DevFabric: Role State Busy

Tags: azure

using Azure SDK 1.4
I have a simple worker role in dev fabric, its not getting beyond busy state - I get "start role failed for one or more roles".

When I debug, the debugger never reaches WorkerRole.OnStart()

why would this be?
how can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the most likely reason for this is either:

- that there is something wrong with the Azure SDK installation
- that your deployed worker role is missing some dependencies somehow

My approach for debugging it would be:

- replace your worker role with a new empty one - just has a forever loop for `Run() { while(true) {} }`
- If the empty worker doesn't run, then it would seem that the SDK is not installed OK :( If this is the case, then try uninstalling and reinstalling - or hopefully someone on here might be able to assist
- if the empty worker runs, then try to work out what is causing the error either by:

  - adding functionality/dependencies to the new empty worker role
  - or removing functionality/dependencies from the old worker role.

I've not seen many problems like this when deploying to the dev fabric, but I've seen lots of them when deploying to Azure (and they take a long time to solve just because of the slow deployment cycle time).

Good luck

Comment: I am using epmty worker role. Change happened when I moved to Azure SDK 1.4 - could it have something to do with 64bit csrun ?

Comment: I am launching csrun from vsix

Comment: If you can use the newer services like web or mobile, please do - that helps :)